# Distributing a maximum value over several cells

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, max, distribution

I'd like to allow someone to select a total of eight items with choice from any four types of item.  So they could have any combination of these:

```
Red Item x8
Black Item x0
White Item x0
Grey Item x0
```

OR

```
Red Item x4
Black Item x4
White Item x0
Grey Item x0
```

OR

```
Red Item x1
Black Item x3
White Item x4
Grey Item x0
```

and so on...

The user should not be able to exceed eight (or whatever number is set).

Is there any Excel function allowing this kind of distribution over several cells while enforcing a limit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With a layout like this:

[image: SO29538233 example]

a Data Validation rule Allow: Custom, Formula:

```
=SUM($A2:$D2)<9
```

will prevent entry of more than a total of 8 in A2:D2.